# Configure Spring Boot SOAP web services on a different port than the web api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have Jetty container in the main application context running on port 8080 path /. Current state is that soap services are configured on a subpath /ws but on the same port.

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SoapConfiguration extends WsConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }
}
```

What i want is for the rest of the web api running on port 8080, but all @Endpoint classes sit on a different port say 8003.

I understand a possible solution is to create different modules and wrap them together with a application context hierarchy https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-hierarchy.

But since all i want is really for just 1 @Endpoint annotated bean to live in a separate context I'd like to find a solution where I don't have to split them into different modules. I assume the idea is to create a child application context which contains a `JettyServletWebServerFactory` factory and the endpoint, but I don't seem to be able to realize it technically.